# Can Linux perf compare per - thread performance?

Tags: multithreading, performance, perf

I know perf can profile a single process or single thread use `perf stat -p tid/pid` or `perf top -p tid/pid`.

But I want to **profile per-thread in a process**, getting separate results for each and every thread.  I want to compare events to see which thread is high consumption. Can perf do this?  If not, which tools can?

Comment: Is your problem Python specific ?

Answer (score 4):

There was proposed patch to add --per-thread option to `perf stat` (and with interval mode `-I 1000` it is possible to see current counters every second for every thread ): https://lwn.net/Articles/649001/ "perf stat: Introduce --per-thread option"  From:     Jiri Olsa,  Date:       Tue, 23 Jun 2015

> adding the possibility to display stat data per thread.
>
> Allowing following commands and output:
>
> $ perf stat  -e cycles,instructions --per-thread -p 30190,30242   ^C
>   Performance counter stats for process id '30190,30242':
>
> ```
>            cat-30190                     0      cycles
>            yes-30242         3,842,525,421      cycles
>            cat-30190                     0      instructions
>            yes-30242        10,370,817,010      instructions
>
>      1.143155657 seconds time elapsed
> ```
>
> Also works under interval mode:
>
> $ perf stat  -e cycles,instructions --per-thread -p 30190,30242 -I
>   1000
>
> ```
> #           time             comm-pid                  counts   unit events
>    1.000073435              cat-30190                89,058      cycles
>    1.000073435              yes-30242         3,360,786,902      cycles                     (100.00%)
>    1.000073435              cat-30190                14,066      instructions
>    1.000073435              yes-30242         9,069,937,462      instructions
>    2.000204830              cat-30190                     0      cycles
>    2.000204830              yes-30242         3,351,667,626      cycles
>    2.000204830              cat-30190                     0      instructions
>    2.000204830              yes-30242         9,045,796,885      instructions   
>   ^C
>    2.771286639              cat-30190                     0      cycles
>    2.771286639              yes-30242         2,593,884,166      cycles
>    2.771286639              cat-30190                     0      instructions
>    2.771286639              yes-30242         7,001,171,191      instructions
> ```
>
> Available in here:
>   git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jolsa/perf.git
>   perf/per_thread

Comment: What if the pid/ tid is not known? In a scenario where the application is invoked like
`perf stat -e <events> ./myApp`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Of course.

You could use `perf_event_open()` system call to open performance counters.
and then use `proctl/ioctl` to read counters.

You could check linux man pages for all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Use '-t' option to specify thread ID. For example:

```
perf stat -t 11111
```

Comment: That will let you attach to one specific thread of an existing process.  Is there a convenient way to attach to all the threads separately like this question asks for?  Like perhaps some shell scripting to find thread IDs and run a separate `perf stat` for each one?  (That wouldn't work well for processes that create and destroy threads over their lifetime; you wouldn't get data from new threads.  But it could work for programs that start a thread pool which doesn't grow or shrink.)

Comment: No idea of any convenient way. If you have source code access of the process, maybe you could teak the thread function to launch the perf command with output to seperate files

Answer (score -3):

Do you see this question?

[How to profile multi-threaded C++ application on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497211/how-to-profile-multi-threaded-c-application-on-linux)

I think you could start with valgrind:

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html